# Interact with localStorage in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I’m trying to get with the help of Laravel Dusk

The value of localStorage

I tried the following variation

```
$value = $browser->value('localStorage.getItem("SKU")');
$value = $browser->text('localStorage.getItem("SKU")');

dd($browser->assertSeeIn("localStorage.getItem('SKU')"))
```

All of them throwback an error.
Are there any other options?

Comment: Do you want to get the item from localStorage?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get an item from local storage

Comment: Did you try this  ```$value = localStorage.getItem("SKU");```   ?

Comment: I wont work because that's not the way Dusk syntax works

I also tried
 $value = $browser->localStorage.getItem("SKU");
but of course I got the following error "Undefined property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `script()` to execute JavaScript and return values:

```php
$value = $browser->script("return localStorage.getItem('SKU')")[0];
```

Comment: I did a small variation in your code and it works.

I used
  $value = $browser->script("return localStorage.getItem('SKU')");
             


What I do not understand why do we need to use “return”?

Can you please explain in order for me to learn?

Comment: You need to return the value from the browser to your Dusk test.

Comment: The return is from JS?

Comment: Yes. You can execute any JavaScript with `script()`.